# Efficiently complete numbers when gap is smaller than n

Tags: r, vectorization

I have the following vector of numbers:

```
v1 = c(1, 5, 10, 11, 13, 20, 22)
```

I would like to complete the missing numbers between every two members in v1 if the gap between them is smaller than `n`, lets say `n=4`. So in this case my result would be:

```
v2 = c(1, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 20, 21, 22)
```

Is there a way to do it efficiently for very long vectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fully Vectorized function that also takes the gap as an argument,

```
f1 <- function(x, n) {
    d1 <- diff(x)
    i1 <- min(x):max(x)
    i2 <- c(FALSE, rep(d1 < n, d1))
    i3 <- i1[i2]
    i4 <- i3[!i3 %in% v1]

    return(sort(c(i4, x)))
}

f1(v1, 4)
#[1]  1  5 10 11 12 13 20 21 22
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone has a better solution without so much indexing, but you could do it this way for example:

```
v1 = c(1, 5, 10, 11, 13, 20, 22)

d <- diff(v1)
idx <- which(d < 4 & d > 1)

unlist(sapply(seq_along(v1), function(x) {
  if (x %in% idx) {
    seq(v1[x], v1[x+1] - 1)
  } else {
    v1[x]
  }
}))

[1]  1  5 10 11 12 13 20 21 22
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a hacky solution that works (probably not the best way to solve this kind of problem). 
Replace `difference < 4` with `:` and parse such string as text:

```
# Input
foo <- c(1, 5, 10, 11, 13, 20, 22)

bar <- ifelse(c(diff(foo) < 4), ":", ",")
# [1] "," "," ":" ":" "," ":"
foobar <- paste(foo[1], paste(bar, foo[-1], collapse = ""), collapse = ",")
# [1] "1 , 5, 10: 11: 13, 20: 22"
eval(parse(text = paste0("c(", foobar, ")")))
# [1] 1  5 10 11 12 13 20 21 22
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have found an elegant solution using lists, using the fact that lists are very efficient objects:

```
v1 = c(1, 5, 10, 11, 13, 20, 23)
Diff = v1 - lag(v1)
ToComplete = seq_along(Diff)[Diff<4 & Diff>1]
L = as.list(v1)
ToComplete = ToComplete[!is.na(ToComplete)]
Diff1 = Diff[ToComplete]
L1= mapply(function(x,y) seq(x-y+1, x-1), L[ToComplete], Diff1, SIMPLIFY = F)
Ltot = c(L, L1)
res = sort(unlist(Ltot))
```